# No transform from [map] to [odom] in ros

Tags: mapping, ros

I created a node to map the turtlebot3_world, since in turtlebot3_world.launch there is no map frame, i assigned `map_msg.header.frame_id = "odom"`inside my code. now i am going to use the created map for localization, I stuck all together in below launch file. the problem is with the origin of the map, although i set the origin of map at [-3,-3,0] it is located at [0,0,0] in rviz and never change, as well as there is another error in rviz ,"No transform from [map] to [odom]" (see the photo below). how can i handle these issues?
thanks in advance.

```
<launch>
    <arg name="my_map" default="$(find robot_laser_grid_mapping)/maps/map.yaml"/>
    <node pkg="just_for_learning"  type="pointstamp.py" name="position_tracker">
            <param name="map_file" value="$(find robot_laser_grid_mapping)/maps/map.yaml" />
    
    </node>
    <node pkg="map_server" type="map_server" name="map_server" args="$(arg my_map)"/>
    <node pkg="teleoperat1" type="key_to_twist.py" name="keys_to_twist" ></node>
    <node pkg="teleoperat1" type="keyboard_drive.py" name="keyboard_driver" ></node>

    <include file="$(find turtlebot3_gazebo)/launch/turtlebot3_world.launch" ></include>

    <include file="$(find turtlebot3_bringup)/launch/turtlebot3_model.launch"></include>

</launch>
```

[rviz environment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yFlsc.png)

Comment: You need to actually publish a transform between the Odom and map frames. Usually this is handled by a localization package; such as gmapping or amcl. [This tutorial](https://wiki.ros.org/pr2_simulator/Tutorials/BuildingAMapInSimulation) can hopefully give some guidance.

Comment: But i am not allowed to use pre created packages, i have to creat my own localization package, not using amcl or gmapping

Comment: Why are you not allowed to use a pre-created package? Is this for a school project